# Const pointer pointing to non-const data

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, type-mismatch

Consider the following case 1:

```
const int n = 5;
int* p = &n;
```

This is invalid, because `&n` is of type `cont int*` and `p` is of type `int *` (type mismatch error).

Now, consider this case 2:

```
int k = 4;
int *const p = &k;
```

This case compiles successfully, without any error. Clearly, `p` is of type `int * const` and `&k` is of type `int *`.  In this case, there is a type mismatch, but it is valid.

Question : Why is the second case valid, even though there is a type mismatch?

Comment: You can assign a non-const to a const, but not vice versa.

Comment: It is always legal to "const"-ify access, but not the other way around. If you have read/write access, it's OK to not use the write part and stay read-only. But if you only have read rights, you can't claim write access.

Comment: Those are two different consts. One is a low-level const and the other is a top-level const.

Comment: 1. Pointer (or reference) to `const` is only a promise not to modify the object via that pointer/reference. It does not mean that the object is unmodifiable. 2. `int *const` is a constant pointer (the pointer cannot be reassigned to point to something else), not a pointer to `const`.

Comment: So you would think that`const int n = 5; int *const p = &n;` is legal? No. It does matter where const is. Constant pointer to int. Of course you can initialize a constant with a gvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this case, there is a type mismatch

No; there is no type mismatch in this case. It is a pointer to non-cost and you initialise it with a pointer to non-const.

Alternatively, if you insist on there being a "mismatch", then it is analogous to the following "mismatch":

```
const int b = 42;
```

> Why is the second case valid

Simply put: The constness of the initialiser is irrelevant to whether it initialises a const object or not. Besides, the initialiser is a prvalue of a non-class type so const qualification doesn't even apply to it.

Comment: I mentioned this on another answer, but wouldn't it be preferable to close this question as a duplicate instead of answering it?

Comment: @cigien If you've found a duplicate, feel free to vote to close.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. Given your knowledge of the content on SO in the c++ tag, I'm sure you could find a duplicate in about the same time as it would take to write an answer, and with your c++ hammer you could close the question yourself. Wouldn't that be preferable to having a lot of identical questions around?

Comment: @cigien, what prevent you from doing it ?

Comment: @NicolasDusart There's nothing preventing me. I could even close this as a duplicate of a target answered by eeorika, as they have answered essentially this question multiple times before. It's true that finding targets can be harder than simply answering a simple question, but my hope was that I could convince a high rep user of the benefit of taking the effort to find a target instead of repeatedly answering basic questions like this. Still, if the priorities of some users are different, there's no rule preventing from behaving in in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `int *const` does mean a const pointer to a non-const int. So there is absolutely no type mismatching between pointer and pointee types.

Secondly, you can always take the address of a non-const variable into a pointer to a const. So this would be valid too:

```
int n = 5;
const int * p = &n;
```